# Add @JsonAutoDetect to third party lib and firebase Java lib

Tags: jackson, firebase

How can I use jackson mix-in with firebase Java lib? I would to add @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY) to a third party lib with mix in.

**Update**
I create a mix in and a module:

```
public interface CustomTabMixIn {
    @JsonIgnore boolean isCustomObject();
} 

public class SFMetadataModule extends SimpleModule
{
  public SFMetadataModule() {
    super("SF-Metadata", new Version(0,0,1,null));
  }
  @Override
  public void setupModule(SetupContext context)
  {
    context.setMixInAnnotations(com.sforce.soap.metadata.CustomTab.class, CustomTabMixIn.class);
  }

}
```

How can I register my module with firebase?

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new SFMetadataModule());
```

Comment: Firebase's Android SDK has Jackson built-in. See this simple sample app that uses it: https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/firebase/androidchat. If you are having trouble making the Jackson bindings work, show the minimal code to reproduce your problem please.

Comment: I have the following error "Conflicting getter definitions for property "emptySpace": com.sforce.soap.metadata.QuickActionLayoutItem#isEmptySpace". I would like to add "@JsonIgnore" to isEmptySpace() method but the class QuickActionLayoutItem is a third party lib so I can't modify it. Thanks,

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Do you know if I can register a jackson module inside the firebase SDK? I would to access to the ObjectMapper that is used to parse the json and register my module. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm... don't know. The Firebase Java SDK uses Jackson internally, but I've never tried adding modules.

Comment: Thanks for your help @FrankvanPuffelen. I will contact the support of Firebase. Hope they will be able to find a solution.

Comment: *Disclaimer: I work at Firebase* you will likely get the same answer.